# Looking for an algo transforming numerical attributes into categorical attributes -cleverly

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, unsupervised-learning

I created an algorithm which works on categorical attributes. The input data comes with categorical attributes, but numerical ones as well.

How can I apply a pre-processing which transforms the numerical attributes into categorical ones, in clever ways:

1. the number of categories can adapt to the distribution of numerical values

-> for example if there are 100 values, 99 of them grouped in a small range, and one clear outlier, then 2 categories should be created.

2. the cutoff between categories should do its best to avoid that two close values are in different categories.

-> for example, it is annoying that for 2 numerical values ranging from 0 to 100, a cutoff at 50 leaves values 49 and 51 in 2 different categories.

Is there a field in computer science which deals with these issues? If there is an algorithm, is it pre-implemented in any language?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE! Could you please phrase your two questions and give examples?

Comment: Hi!  I have phrased the 2 subparts of the question and provided examples. Please explain which sentence you find unclear, and which examples need a clarification.

Comment: You could use an unsupervised clustering technique as a preprocessing technique, for instance...

Comment: yes! Wondering which one would be the most adequate in this case: just one dimension, not need for overkill?

Comment: You need to give more information. If your values are 1,2,3,...,98,99,100, whichever way you hard-cluster them using more than 1 cluster, there will be some close values that will end up being in two different categories. Maybe you would like to look at Unsupervised Fuzzy Clustering techniques then. Or just keep continuous data continuous and use a model for continuous data...

Comment: Look at these functions available for Python: http://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/api/skfuzzy.cluster.html

Comment: @seinecle There's this CV post, which appears today, raises red flags about the approach you're taking. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/what-is-the-benefit-of-breaking-up-a-continuous-predictor-variable

Comment: I have not taken any approach yet! Here is one alternative to clusters: considering the issue has "which width for the bars of my histogram", aka the bins problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width